# Using log4j as implementation for log4j2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have a system for which I'm writing a plugin. The system uses log4j, and I cannot change its dependencies, so it is not possible for me to remove the log4j implementation. My plugin makes reference to other libraries that, on the other hand, use log4j2. I can change the jars provided for that.

So I'm looking for an log4j2 adapter that will route the messages to the log4j implementation, like the log4j to slf4j adapter.

Comment: Which module you want to do the actual logging? log4j(1) or log4j2?

Comment: What if you route log4j2 to slf4j then set up log4j as the implementation for slf4j? See [Log4j to SLF4J Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html)

Comment: @D.B. I actually tried that out, and found that the existing log4j was already set as slf4j, so I didn't need to do anything else.

Comment: @sazzad log4j(1)